handle font family and font size using the PDF-lib node js package
I'm working on generating and inserting data into the existing pdf, and applying font size and font family to the text field of PDF.
this is my code snippet to attach the font.
const { PDFDocument, StandardFonts } = require("pdf-lib");
const fontFile = join(__dirname, '../ARIALBD.TTF')
const { join } = require("path");
// array of forms with schema
      for (const iterator of forms) {
          let formName = iterator.url;
          const source = join(__dirname, `../public/forms/${formName}.pdf`);
          const pdfData = fs.readFileSync(source);
          const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(pdfData);
          pdfDoc.registerFontkit(fontkit);
          const fontBytes = fs.readFileSync(fontFile);
          let font = await pdfDoc.embedFont(fontBytes);

          let formSchema = pdfDoc.getForm();
          const fields = formSchema.getFields();
          fields.forEach((field) => {
          if (field.constructor.name == "PDFTextField") {
             textField = formSchema.getTextField(field.getName())
             textField.setText("sample text")
             textField.acroField.setDefaultAppearance('/F3 0 Tf 0 g')
          }
       });
      const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
      let des = destination + `${docName.join("_")}.pdf`;
      fs.writeFileSync(des, pdfBytes);
}

It works fine to scale font in PDF, but after generating a PDF with pdf-lib, I'm updating some data into the field and after changing data my font family is changing to Curior new bold and font size is getting larger.
below image is from my working module.
I've been trying this for a long time not getting any solution. Thanks in advance for any help.


The fonts were set to Courier by the Adobe Server and in most PDF viewers will respect that Adobe XML default by substitute a similar font. but the Viewer is the one that fixes the appearance and thus the Edits must be done using Adobe Products as per the inbuilt scripted warnings.


An Acrobat web viewer such as MS Edge Powered by Acrobat.

Another non Adobe PDF editor with its own fonts will be different appearances. But that suggests the document has been edited without using the inbuilt Adobe proprietary systems, thus invalidating the internal scripts.


pdf-lib does not support reading rich text fields. Nor do most PDF readers and writers. Rich text fields are based on XFA (XML Forms Architecture). Relatively few PDFs use rich text fields or XFA. Unlike PDF itself, XFA is not an ISO standard. XFA has been deprecated in PDF 2.0:


I just understand the PDF is behaviour based on the tool, but not sure which solution should I apply for the font change.
